# Bash Script can't find command while command can be executed in my bash

Tags: bash, script

I have a Python script that i want to restart if it crashes. So i created a Bash starter script that starts and restarts the Python script in /usr/local/bin/starter

Here's the starter script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
until myPythonScript; do
    sleep 1s;
done
```

This starter script i run @reboot (cronjob).

My Python script is also located in /usr/local/bin/myPythonScript so i can start it just by typing `myPythonScript`.

Now is my problem that i receive the error message that my `/usr/local/bin/starter` can't find the command `myPythonScript`. Does anybody know why and how i could solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the full path. If you are using a crontable, cron does not have the same env, including path, that you do.

You might also consider inittab. It can ensure processes are running and restart if they are not present.